# How to make Div disabled in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried With fieldset but its disabling only input field and remaining dropdown are not disabled  . Is there any solution for my question ??

Comment: Please post your code. Show your tries

Comment: Post your code what you had tried yet?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first to form your question better. Then, to allow others to help you, please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or whatever you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Use "disabled" in your div; or "ng-disabled" if you want to enable/disable it based on a condition.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

What I think you're trying to do is to place a condition on a div, and when that condition is true, you want to disable the div and all child elements.

You can mark a div as disabled using `ng-disabled` like this:

```
<div ng-disabled="expression">
    <input type="text"> <!-- Won't be disabled! -->
    <select> <!-- Also won't be disabled! -->
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

However, that does not propagate to child elements.

See the doco for ng-disabled here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

## Solution

You will have to add the `ng-disabled` attribute to each child element in the div you want disabled.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="expression">
    <select ng-disabled="expression">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

## Extra

Keeping the `ng-disabled` attribute on the div is **not** required to disable the child elements, however it can be used as a useful css selector.

For example, maybe you want to set the opacity for the whole div when it is disabled.

```
<div class="special-div" ng-disabled="expression">
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="expression">
    <select ng-disabled="expression">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Using this css

```
div.special-div[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("yourDivID").style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

---

For Example :

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <h1>This is my division</h1>
</div>
```

Then code will be as below :

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.pointerEvents = "none";
```